# Screwed up audio / pulseaudio configuration in Linux Mint 21: how to repair?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I somehow managed to screw up my audio configuration (maybe it was a jointed force of me and an update). It started with bluetooth not working. After reinstallation of `pulseaudio`, `bluez-alsa-utils` and some dilettantish digging in default profiles bluetooth returned. However, now HDMI output and profiles of my NVIDIA graphics / audio card are messed up: in `alsamixer` only one "< S/PDIF >" and in `pavucontrol` only one HDMI/Display port appears (the card has actually one DVI, HDMI and 3 Display ports). Also only one port is listed under `pacmd list-cards` or `list-sinks` and only few profiles seem to be available (in other linux machines with similar cards there are dozens of profiles).

I can switch of and on bluetooth and the right profile appears in pacucontrol or in audio settings but if I connect an additional monitor (TV screen) via HDMI cable, no additional profile appears and either no sound comes (it stays in the primary monitor) or it comes from both monitors simultaneously. Video transfer on the other hand works fine. Interestingly `xrandr --verbose`  lists all relevant ports (see outputs below).

I think, I somehow deleted or messed up an essential audio configuration file but I do not know which and how to restore that configuration. Who can help me?

here the relevant diagnostics:
`inxi -Fxz`

```
 Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
   Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.5 Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera
   base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
 Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B450-I GAMING v: Rev 1.xx
   serial: <superuser required> BIOS: American Megatrends v: 4901
   date: 07/25/2022
CPU:
 Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+
   rev: 2 cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 16 MiB
 Speed (MHz): avg: 2014 high: 2792 min/max: 2200/3700 boost: enabled
   cores: 1: 1955 2: 2404 3: 1716 4: 2008 5: 2022 6: 1913 7: 1886 8: 1885
   9: 1786 10: 2792 11: 1891 12: 2402 13: 1886 14: 1903 15: 1886 16: 1890
   bogomips: 118177
 Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
 Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] vendor: ZOTAC driver: nvidia
   v: 515.86.01 bus-ID: 06:00.0
 Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
   unloaded: modesetting gpu: nvidia resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz
   2: 1920x1080~60Hz
 OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
   v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.86.01 direct render: Yes
Audio:
 Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio vendor: ZOTAC
   driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 06:00.1
 Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
   v: kernel bus-ID: 08:00.3
 Device-3: Nam Tai E&E Products or OmniVision Sony Playstation Eye
   type: USB driver: ov534,snd-usb-audio bus-ID: 3-3:4
 Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-56-generic running: yes
 Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
 Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.63 running: yes
Network:
 Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb v: kernel
   port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
 IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
 Device-2: Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter vendor: ASUSTeK
   driver: rtw_8822be v: kernel port: c000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
 IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter>
 IF-ID-1: lxcbr0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
 Device-1: ASUSTek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
   bus-ID: 1-8:5
 Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
   bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.2
RAID:
 Device-1: default type: zfs status: ONLINE level: linear raw:
   size: 18.5 GiB free: 18.5 GiB zfs-fs: size: 17.92 GiB free: 17.92 GiB
 Components: Online: 1:
Drives:
 Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 1.23 TiB (67.8%)
 ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-22MFCA0
   size: 931.51 GiB
 ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-00BBHA0
   size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
 ID-1: / size: 915.82 GiB used: 779.19 GiB (85.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
 ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
 System Temperatures: cpu: 39.8 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 34 C
 Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 40%
Info:
 Processes: 443 Uptime: 32m Memory: 31.27 GiB used: 2.91 GiB (9.3%)
 Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 Packages: 3748 Shell: Bash
 v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

`xrandr --verbose` sees all ports of my card and also connected monitors:

```
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   Identifier: 0x1bc
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Clones:    
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: TMDS 
       supported: TMDS
   ConnectorType: DVI-D 
   ConnectorNumber: 0 
   _ConnectorLocation: 0 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   Identifier: 0x1bd
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Clones:    
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
       supported: DisplayPort
   ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
   ConnectorNumber: 4 
   _ConnectorLocation: 4 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x1bf) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   Identifier: 0x1be
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
   Brightness: 1.0
   Clones:    
   CRTC:       1
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   EDID: 
       00ffffffffffff004dd901a401010101
       0113010380a05a780a0dc9a057479827
       12484c21080081800101010101010101
       010101010101023a801871382d40582c
       450040846300001e011d007251d01e20
       6e28550040846300001e000000fc0053
       4f4e592054560a2020202020000000fd
       00303e0e460f000a2020202020200109
       02032cf0501f10140513041211161503
       02070601202609070715075083010000
       68030c00300080000fe2007b023a80d0
       72382d40102c458040846300001e011d
       00bc52d01e20b828554040846300001e
       011d8018711c1620582c250040846300
       009e011d80d0721c1620102c25804084
       6300009e000000000000000000000053
   _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: TMDS 
       supported: TMDS
   ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
   ConnectorNumber: 4 
   _ConnectorLocation: 4 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
 1920x1080 (0x1bf) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c0) 148.350MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c1) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c2) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  26.97KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  23.98Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c3) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1124           clock  60.05Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c4) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1124           clock  60.00Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c5) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
       h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1124           clock  50.04Hz
 1280x1024 (0x1c6) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
       v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
 1280x720 (0x1c7) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
       v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
 1280x720 (0x1c8) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
       v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
 1280x720 (0x1c9) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
       v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
 1024x768 (0x1ca) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
       v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
 800x600 (0x1cb) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
       v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
 720x576 (0x1cc) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
       v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
 720x480 (0x1cd) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
       v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
 640x480 (0x1ce) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
       v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
 640x480 (0x1cf) 25.170MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.46KHz
       v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.93Hz
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (0x1bf) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 544mm x 303mm
   Identifier: 0x1d0
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
   Brightness: 1.0
   Clones:    
   CRTC:       0
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   EDID: 
       00ffffffffffff0026cd326124060000
       201d010380361e782a9055a75553a028
       135054a56b80710081408180a940b300
       9500950fd1c0023a801871382d40582c
       4500202f2100001e000000ff00313135
       34333933323031353732000000fd0037
       4c1e5312000a202020202020000000fc
       00504c32353330480a202020202001c6
       02032bf14f9005040302011112131406
       0715161f230907078301000065030c00
       1000681a00000101284be6023a801871
       382d40582c4500202f2100001f011d80
       18711c1620582c2500202f2100009e01
       1d007251d01e206e285500202f210000
       1e2a4480a07038274030203500202f21
       00001a000000000000000000000000ab
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: TMDS 
       supported: TMDS
   ConnectorType: HDMI 
   ConnectorNumber: 3 
   _ConnectorLocation: 3 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
 1920x1080 (0x1bf) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1d1) 174.500MHz +HSync -VSync
       h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  83.89KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1119           clock  74.97Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c0) 148.350MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c1) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c3) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1124           clock  60.05Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c4) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
       h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1124           clock  60.00Hz
 1920x1080 (0x1c5) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
       h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
       v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1124           clock  50.04Hz
 1680x1050 (0x1d2) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
       h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
       v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
 1600x1200 (0x1d3) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
       v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
 1440x900 (0x1d4) 136.750MHz -HSync +VSync
       h: width  1440 start 1536 end 1688 total 1936 skew    0 clock  70.64KHz
       v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  942           clock  74.98Hz
 1440x900 (0x1d5) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
       h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
       v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
 1280x1024 (0x1d6) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
       v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
 1280x1024 (0x1c6) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
       v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
 1280x960 (0x1d7) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
       v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
 1280x720 (0x1c7) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
       v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
 1280x720 (0x1c8) 74.180MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
       v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
 1280x720 (0x1c9) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
       v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
 1152x720 (0x1d8) 67.320MHz -HSync +VSync
       h: width  1152 start 1208 end 1328 total 1504 skew    0 clock  44.76KHz
       v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
 1024x768 (0x1d9) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
       v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
 1024x768 (0x1ca) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
       v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
 800x600 (0x1da) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
       v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
 800x600 (0x1cb) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
       h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
       v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
 720x576 (0x1cc) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
       v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
 720x480 (0x1cd) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
       v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
 640x480 (0x1db) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
       v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
 640x480 (0x1ce) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
       v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
 640x480 (0x1cf) 25.170MHz -HSync -VSync
       h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.46KHz
       v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.93Hz
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   Identifier: 0x1dc
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Clones:    
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
       supported: DisplayPort
   ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
   ConnectorNumber: 2 
   _ConnectorLocation: 2 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   Identifier: 0x1dd
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Clones:    
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: TMDS 
       supported: TMDS
   ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
   ConnectorNumber: 2 
   _ConnectorLocation: 2 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   Identifier: 0x1de
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Clones:    
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
       supported: DisplayPort
   ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
   ConnectorNumber: 1 
   _ConnectorLocation: 1 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   Identifier: 0x1df
   Timestamp:  508854
   Subpixel:   unknown
   Clones:    
   CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
   Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
               0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
              filter: 
   CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
       0 1 
   CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
   BorderDimensions: 4 
       supported: 4
   Border: 0 0 0 0 
       range: (0, 65535)
   SignalFormat: TMDS 
       supported: TMDS
   ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
   ConnectorNumber: 1 
   _ConnectorLocation: 1 
   non-desktop: 0 
       supported: 0, 1
```

However, in `pacmd list-cards` and `pacmd list-sinks` only one port and a few profiles appear

```
   index: 0
   name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_06_00.1>
   driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
   owner module: 6
   properties:
       alsa.card = "0"
       alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
       alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 67"
       alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
       device.bus_path = "pci-0000:06:00.1"
       sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:06:00.1/sound/card0"
       device.bus = "pci"
       device.vendor.id = "10de"
       device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
       device.product.id = "10f1"
       device.product.name = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
       device.string = "0"
       device.description = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
       device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
   profiles:
       output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: unknown)
       off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
   active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
   sinks:
       alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.1.hdmi-stereo/#0: GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)
   sources:
       alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)
   ports:
       hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
           properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
   index: 1
   name: <alsa_card.usb-OmniVision_Technologies__Inc._USB_Camera-B4.09.24.1-01>
   driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
   owner module: 7
   properties:
       alsa.card = "2"
       alsa.card_name = "USB Camera-B4.09.24.1"
       alsa.long_card_name = "OmniVision Technologies, Inc. USB Camera-B4.09.24.1 at usb-0000:07:00.3-3, high"
       alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
       device.bus_path = "pci-0000:07:00.3-usb-0:3:1.1"
       sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.1/sound/card2"
       udev.id = "usb-OmniVision_Technologies__Inc._USB_Camera-B4.09.24.1-01"
       device.bus = "usb"
       device.vendor.id = "1415"
       device.vendor.name = "Nam Tai E&E Products Ltd. or OmniVision Technologies, Inc."
       device.product.id = "2000"
       device.product.name = "Sony Playstation Eye"
       device.serial = "OmniVision_Technologies__Inc._USB_Camera-B4.09.24.1"
       device.string = "2"
       device.description = "Sony Playstation Eye"
       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
       device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
   profiles:
       input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
       off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
   active profile: <off>
   index: 2
   name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_08_00.3>
   driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
   owner module: 8
   properties:
       alsa.card = "1"
       alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
       alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc800000 irq 69"
       alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
       device.bus_path = "pci-0000:08:00.3"
       sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:08:00.3/sound/card1"
       device.bus = "pci"
       device.vendor.id = "1022"
       device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
       device.product.id = "1457"
       device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller"
       device.string = "1"
       device.description = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller"
       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
       device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
   profiles:
       input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: no)
       output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: no)
       output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: no)
       off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
   active profile: <off>
   ports:
       analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
           properties:
               device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
       analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
           properties:
               device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
       analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
           properties:
               
       analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
           properties:
               
       analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
           properties:
               device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

```
 * index: 0
   name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
   driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
   flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
   state: SUSPENDED
   suspend cause: IDLE
   priority: 9030
   volume: front-left: 56023 /  85% / -4.09 dB,   front-right: 56023 /  85% / -4.09 dB
           balance 0.00
   base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
   volume steps: 65537
   muted: no
   current latency: 0.00 ms
   max request: 0 KiB
   max rewind: 0 KiB
   monitor source: 0
   sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
   channel map: front-left,front-right
                Stereo
   used by: 0
   linked by: 0
   configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1837.33 ms
   card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_06_00.1>
   module: 6
   properties:
       alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
       device.api = "alsa"
       device.class = "sound"
       alsa.class = "generic"
       alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
       alsa.name = "Generic Digital"
       alsa.id = "Generic Digital"
       alsa.subdevice = "0"
       alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
       alsa.device = "3"
       alsa.card = "0"
       alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
       alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfc080000 irq 67"
       alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
       device.bus_path = "pci-0000:06:00.1"
       sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:06:00.1/sound/card0"
       device.bus = "pci"
       device.vendor.id = "10de"
       device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
       device.product.id = "10f1"
       device.product.name = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller"
       device.string = "hdmi:0"
       device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
       device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
       device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
       device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
       device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
       device.description = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
       module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
       device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
   ports:
       hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
           properties:
               device.icon_name = "video-display"
   active port: <hdmi-output-0>
```

Comment: Log off, log in in Linux console, e.g. tty2 (Ctrl + Alt + F2), run `rm -rf ~/.local/state/wireplumber`. Go back to your display manager and check if everything works.

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov You are my hero! Now everything works as it should! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log off
2. log in in Linux console, e.g. tty2 (Ctrl + Alt + F2)
3. run `rm -rf ~/.local/state/wireplumber`
4. go back to your display manager (Alt + F1 or F7) and check if everything works.

To think of it, maybe I should file a bug report/missing feature request because I've done exactly this several times myself. The feature would be something like: `wireplumber --resetsettings`. And it's [done](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/wireplumber/-/issues/397).